# PHP Excel - The file you are trying to open .xls is in a different format than specified by the file extension

Tags: php, excel

Good Morning,

I am use a API JASPER "JasperClient.php" where i use the function runReport to return a xls and in php code i want to download Excel File from the server.

Setting the header:

header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=myfile.xls');

When i'm download the file and try to open the says:

The file you are trying to open, 'filename.xls', is in a different format than specified by the file extension. Verify that the file is not corrupted and is from a trusted source before opening the file. Do you want to open the file now?

Can you help me please? 
Thank you .

Comment: easy check: can a proper microsoft excel open the file you're trying to send? if yes, the problem is in your download, if no, the problem is in your file. Creating excel files isn't very easy.

Comment: Are you creating an actual MS Excel BIFF format file; or simply a csv file, or html markup, and just giving it an .xls extension ?

Comment: I don't understand: you preview the report in iReport but you create the Excel file in php?  Jasper is written in Java and IIRC uses POI to generate Excelfiles, so I don't understand where php comes into the picture...

Comment: no the microsoft excel can't open the xls file
, but the excel preview in jaspersoft can!

Comment: Perhaps if you showed how you're creating the file, or at least indicated which library you're using to create it

Comment: You'll have to explain that procedure a bit more in detail, are you saying here that you have php code that transforms jrxml into xls?  You should probably add your (php) code to show us what's going on...

Comment: I rephrased the question ...

Answer (score 2):

Are you creating Excel 2007 files? If so try using mimetype application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet and file extension .xslx

Comment: I am creating a excel 2003 but i already tried with 2007 and the same error occurs

Comment: Have you opened the file in a text editor? Maybe there is some PHP warning/error message included in the file?

Comment: @user2968390 also, if you use a GNU/Linux machine, what's the output of `file myfile.xls` ?