# Error while opening an Excel file that generated using phpExcel

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpexcel

I am trying to generate an **Excel** file using **phpExcel** library in **Codeigniter**.
The problem is that while downloading the file it shows characters in in undifined formats

While opening the downloaded file it shows the message that is an different format, please refer the pic
[image]

and while opening the file content as

[image]

and my code stuff is:

```
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
    $this->load->library('excel');
    $sheet = new PHPExcel();
    $objWorkSheet = $sheet->createSheet();
    $sheet->getProperties()->setTitle('JDI Problem Improvement Strip')->setDescription('JDI Problem Improvement Strip');
    $sheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

$sheet_writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($sheet, 'Excel5');
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="01simple.xls"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
$sheet_writer->save('php://output');
```

Comment: which excel version you are trying to create? 2007?

Comment: Open the file in a text editor. Look for leading/trailing whitespace characters, any BOM header, any plaintext PHP error messages or any html markup in the file, then find where your script is echoing those into the output stream

Answer (score 0):

Are you creating Excel 2007 files? If so try using `mimetype application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet` and file extension `.xslx`

refer - [PHP Excel - The file you are trying to open .xls is in a different format than specified by the file extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19856355/php-excel-the-file-you-are-trying-to-open-xls-is-in-a-different-format-than-s)

Comment: where to specify this mime type, and i am using "PHPExcel" library to generate excel file not "API JASPER" as mentioned in link by you

Comment: yeah, mime tipe is already "application/vnd.ms-excel", its specified under "mimes" in config

Answer (score 0):

```
ob_end_clean(); 
ob_start();
```

It cleans the buffer and get correct output. At least for me it resolve the issue.